# C# abstract class and covariant

Tags: c#, refactoring, ooad

i have some code like this:

```
class DataFilter
{
    List<Animal> animals=null;
    public function1(string TypeOfData)
    {
        if(TypeOfData=="cat"){//get cats from database and do something}
        else if(TypeOfData=="dog")
        {//get dogs & do something}
    }
}
class Animal
{}
class Cat:Animal
{}
class Dog:Animal
{}
```

if i reuse the DataFilter class:

```
 class CatFilter:DataFilter
 {
 }
```

how to reuse list animals property???

how to refactor it to split the function1 into different class

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>() { new Dog(), new Cat() };
 foreach (var animal in animals)
      animal.DoSomething();
```

--

```
class Animal
{ public virtual void DoSomething() { } }

class Cat : Animal
{ public override void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("CAT"); } }

class Dog : Animal
{ public override void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("DOG"); } }
```

**--EDIT--**

I still can not understand what you really want. But seeing the keyword `filter` makes me think

```
var groupedAnimals = animals.GroupBy(a => a.GetType())
                         .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Animals = g.ToList() })
                         .ToList();
```

or

```
var cats = animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList();
```

Comment: sorry, but that's not what i mean

Comment: @Kevin But what you try to mean isn't clear. Would you think to rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use concept *polymorphism* into your design, example:

```
class DataFilter
{
    List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>() { new Dog(), new Cat() };

    public function1()
    {
        foreach (var animal in animals)
            animal.Do();
    }
}

abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void Do();
}

class Cat: Animal
{
    public override void Do() {}  
}

class Dog: Animal
{
    public override void Do() {}
}
```

Comment: @Kevin: What do you mean? Could you update your question, seems it is not clear much

Comment: i think DataFilter can be a base class

Comment: @Kevin: could you update your question for more clear, I still dont get your point